# Oracle query to Get data in separate columns based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have table like below.

[image] like below

the result I need is IN and OUT in different columns as shown in RESULT table. If the first entry for a particular vehicle is **IN** then I need the immediate **OUT** else keep it blank.
But if the first record for a particular vehicle is **OUT** then I need to get the last **IN** record for that vehicle for the previous date,if exists any(example in the fig for **veh2**).

Is there a way to do it using oracle query? Can anyone help me in anyway doing this?Thanks in advance.

Data as text:
08/04/15    veh1    in  08:00:00 AM

08/04/15    veh1    in  08:15:00 AM

08/04/15    veh1    out 08:17:00 AM

08/04/15    veh1    in  08:20:00 AM

08/04/15    veh1    out 08:50:00 AM

08/04/15    veh1    in  09:15:00 AM

08/04/15    veh1    out 09:30:00 AM

08/04/15    veh1    in  10:15:00 AM

08/04/15    veh2    out 08:00:00 AM

08/04/15    veh2    in  08:15:00 AM

08/04/15    veh2    out 09:50:00 AM

08/04/15    veh2    in  10:10:00 AM

I have time and date in the same column with datatype Date.

Comment: What have you tried before asking this question? Also, provide a link to the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with the data in your question.

Comment: I did all coding in the fron end, that is using c#. But that makes the process very slow.

Comment: It would be better to put data as text instead of image...

Comment: I have Changed data to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ccd5/1)

**Schema Details**

```
create table vehicle_entry
(dt date,
 vehicle_no varchar2(20),
 entry_mode varchar2(10),
 entry_date varchar2(20));

 insert into vehicle_entry values('05-Aug-2015','v1','IN','08:00:00 AM');
 insert into vehicle_entry values('05-Aug-2015','v1','IN','08:15:00 AM');
 insert into vehicle_entry values('05-Aug-2015','v1','OUT','08:17:00 AM');
 insert into vehicle_entry values('05-Aug-2015','v1','IN','08:20:00 AM');
 insert into vehicle_entry values('05-Aug-2015','v1','OUT','08:50:00 AM');
 insert into vehicle_entry values('05-Aug-2015','v1','IN','10:15:00 AM');
 insert into vehicle_entry values('04-Aug-2015','v2','IN','10:12:00 PM');
 insert into vehicle_entry values('05-Aug-2015','v2','OUT','08:20:00 AM');
```

**Select Query**

```
select to_char(complete_date, 'mm/dd/rrrr') as dt,vehicle_no, in_date,(select out_date from
(select rownum as rn,vehicle_no, entry_mode, to_date(to_char(dt,'dd-Mon-rrrr') || ' ' || entry_date, 'dd-Mon-rrrr hh:mi:ss AM') complete_date,
case when entry_mode='IN' then to_date(to_char(dt,'dd-Mon-rrrr') || ' ' || entry_date, 'dd-Mon-rrrr hh:mi:ss AM') else null end as in_date,
case when entry_mode='OUT' then to_date(to_char(dt,'dd-Mon-rrrr') || ' ' || entry_date, 'dd-Mon-rrrr hh:mi:ss AM') else null end as out_date
from vehicle_entry
order by vehicle_no, complete_date) b where b.rn=a.rn+1 and b.vehicle_no=a.vehicle_no
) as out_date
from
(
select rownum as rn,vehicle_no, entry_mode, to_date(to_char(dt,'dd-Mon-rrrr') || ' ' || entry_date, 'dd-Mon-rrrr hh:mi:ss AM') complete_date,
case when entry_mode='IN' then to_date(to_char(dt,'dd-Mon-rrrr') || ' ' || entry_date, 'dd-Mon-rrrr hh:mi:ss AM') else null end as in_date,
case when entry_mode='OUT' then to_date(to_char(dt,'dd-Mon-rrrr') || ' ' || entry_date, 'dd-Mon-rrrr hh:mi:ss AM') else null end as out_date
from vehicle_entry
order by vehicle_no, complete_date
) a
where in_date is not null
order by vehicle_no,1
```

**Output**

```
|         DT | VEHICLE_NO |                  IN_DATE |                 OUT_DATE |
|------------|------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
| 08/05/2015 |         v1 | August, 05 2015 08:00:00 |                   (null) |
| 08/05/2015 |         v1 | August, 05 2015 08:15:00 | August, 05 2015 08:17:00 |
| 08/05/2015 |         v1 | August, 05 2015 08:20:00 | August, 05 2015 08:50:00 |
| 08/05/2015 |         v1 | August, 05 2015 10:15:00 |                   (null) |
| 08/04/2015 |         v2 | August, 04 2015 22:12:00 | August, 05 2015 08:20:00 |
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out. I get the proper output till now. I will try to know and understand the query as well. thanks again